# How do I refactor two case value expressions into one?

Tags: f#

**How do I refactor two case value expressions into one?**

I'm afraid that I'm still not clear on how to remove duplication from this logic:

```
match redPiece with
| Checker checker -> checker |> set (checker |> attemptJump blackChecker yIncrementValue)
| King    king    -> king    |> set (king    |> attemptJump blackChecker yIncrementValue)
```

This question is probably a **[duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38657045/how-can-i-return-a-parameter-as-a-union-case-value/38660059#38660059)**. However, I am still struggling to refactor this type of code smell.

How do I actually implement the wrapper function that one of the posters suggested on the [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38657045/how-can-i-return-a-parameter-as-a-union-case-value/38660059#38660059) I provided?

**Here's the complete function:**

```
let jumpBlack ((blackChecker:BlackChecker),(blackCheckers:BlackChecker list))  (redPiece:RedPiece) =

    let yIncrementValue = -1
    let minY = 0

    let set position piece =
       match position with
       | pos when pos = piece   -> position , blackCheckers
       | _                      -> position , blackCheckers |> remove blackChecker

    match redPiece with
    | Checker checker -> checker |> set (checker |> attemptJump blackChecker yIncrementValue)
    | King    king    -> king    |> set (king    |> attemptJump blackChecker yIncrementValue)
```

**The entire domain can be found here:**

```
(* Types *)
type BlackOption = NorthEast | NorthWest
type RedOption =   SouthEast | SouthWest

type KingOption = 
    | NorthEast 
    | NorthWest
    | SouthEast 
    | SouthWest

type Position =     { X:int; Y:int }

type BlackChecker = Position
type RedChecker =   Position
type BlackKing =    Position
type RedKing =      Position

type King = 
    | BlackKing of BlackKing
    | RedKing of RedKing

type RedPiece = 
    | Checker of RedChecker 
    | King of RedKing

type BlackPiece = 
    | BlackChecker of BlackChecker 
    | BlackKing of BlackKing

(* Private *)
let private remove item list = list |> List.filter (fun x -> x <> item)

let private setRowPosition y1 y2 y3 index =
    match index with 
    | x when x < 4 -> { X=x; Y=y1 }
    | x when x < 8 -> { X=x-4; Y=y2 }
    | _            -> { X=index-8; Y=y3 }

let private set (x, y) positions (position:Position) =
    match not (positions |> List.exists (fun pos -> pos = { X=x; Y=y })) with
    | true -> { X=x; Y=y }
    | false -> position

let private attemptJump target yDirection source =
    let updateX value = { X=target.X + value
                          Y=target.Y + yDirection }
    match source with
    | position when position.Y + yDirection = target.Y &&
                    position.X + 1 = target.X -> updateX 1

    | position when position.Y + yDirection = target.Y &&
                    position.X - 1 = target.X -> updateX -1
    | _ -> source

let private initializeBlack () =
    let setPosition index =
        index |> setRowPosition 7 6 5

    let blackCheckers = List.init 12 setPosition |> List.map (fun pos -> { X=pos.X; Y=pos.Y })
    blackCheckers

let private initializeRed () =
    let setPosition index =
        index |> setRowPosition 0 1 2

    let redCheckers =   List.init 12 setPosition |> List.map (fun pos -> { X=pos.X; Y=pos.Y })
    redCheckers

(* Exposed *)
let moveBlack direction positions (checker:BlackChecker) =
    let position = checker

    match direction with
    | BlackOption.NorthEast -> (positions, position) ||> set ((position.X + 1), (position.Y + 1 ))
    | BlackOption.NorthWest -> (positions, position) ||> set ((position.X - 1), (position.Y + 1 ))

let moveRed direction positions (checker:RedChecker) =
    let position = checker

    match direction with
    | RedOption.SouthEast -> (positions, position) ||> set ((position.X + 1), (position.Y - 1 ))
    | RedOption.SouthWest -> (positions, position) ||> set ((position.X - 1), (position.Y - 1 ))

let moveKing direction positions (king:King) =

    let position = match king with
                   | King.BlackKing bk -> bk
                   | King.RedKing   rk -> rk

    let result = match direction with
                 | NorthEast -> (positions, position) ||> set ((position.X + 1), (position.Y + 1 ))
                 | NorthWest -> (positions, position) ||> set ((position.X - 1), (position.Y + 1 ))
                 | SouthEast -> (positions, position) ||> set ((position.X + 1), (position.Y - 1 ))
                 | SouthWest -> (positions, position) ||> set ((position.X - 1), (position.Y - 1 ))

    match king with
    | King.BlackKing _ -> King.BlackKing result
    | King.RedKing   _ -> King.RedKing   result

let jumpRed ((redChecker:RedChecker), (redCheckers:RedChecker list)) (blackChecker:BlackChecker) =

    let yIncrementValue = 1
    let maxY = 7
    let position = blackChecker |> attemptJump redChecker yIncrementValue

    match position with
    | pos when pos = blackChecker -> BlackChecker position , redCheckers
    | pos when pos.Y = maxY       -> BlackKing    position , redCheckers |> remove redChecker
    | _                           -> BlackChecker position , redCheckers |> remove redChecker

let jumpBlack ((blackChecker:BlackChecker),(blackCheckers:BlackChecker list))  (redPiece:RedPiece) =

    let yIncrementValue = -1
    let minY = 0

    let set position piece =
       match position with
       | pos when pos = piece   -> position , blackCheckers
       | _                      -> position , blackCheckers |> remove blackChecker

    match redPiece with
    | Checker checker -> checker |> set (checker |> attemptJump blackChecker yIncrementValue)
    | King    king    -> king    |> set (king    |> attemptJump blackChecker yIncrementValue)
```

Comment: Maybe I'm wrong, but separating black and red in separate type is a wrong approach. A pawn do exactly the same thing regardless of it's color (going to **it's** left or right). The color/player is only a parameter of it's state. The duplication IMO comes from there.

Comment: This is a pretty strange domain model. Like @Sehnsucht said you have a lot of duplication in the definitions there.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. My intent was to have the compiler enforce the rules of checker movement based on color and king-status. Hence, I have ben trying to practice the notion of making illegal states unrepresentable and have been failing miserably.

Comment: @ScottNimrod I'd suggest reading [Enterprise Tic-Tac-Toe](https://fsharpforfunandprofit.com/posts/enterprise-tic-tac-toe/) It could contain some clues about how to model things without separating things AND enforcing game rules

Comment: How far do you intend to take your checkers program? All the way to the point it has an AI and can play and learn? Here is a link that has way more detail than you are asking [(See Assignment 2)](https://people.cs.pitt.edu/~lucalugini/courses/fall2015/CS2710/) but if I were doing this project I would be reading all the notes and code with interest as it is basic enough to understand but has enough depth to keep you going for a few weeks if not months. The code is Python, but the concepts will translate to F#.

Comment: I just wanted to slap a UI over it and rest assured that illegal moves aren't compilable. I didn't have plans for AI. I feel like I was promised one thing about FP but wasn't told how hard it would be to achieve it. Then again, I am still and forever practicing.

Comment: I try to focus on state transitions. I thought TDD / RGR would flush out a basic domain model. Unfortunately, my current practice of it isn't generating my desired result.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would remove the duplication like that:

```
match redPiece with
    | Checker piece
    | King    piece    -> piece    |> set (piece    |> attemptJump blackChecker yIncrementValue)
```